# A strange duplication on python's log

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, multiprocessing

I am using python multiprocessing, logging on a separate file for each process.
Unfortunately, some logs appears to be duplicated in a strange manner, like this (I use an image because I can't paste NUL chars).

[image]

This is log configuration for each process

```
class RunningInfoFileHandler(FileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=False):
        FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)

    def emit(self, record):
        if not record.levelno == logging.INFO:
            return
        FileHandler.emit(self, record)

def generate_session_log_config(project_name, scenario_name,  index, operation='execution'):
    # todo refactoring of program strings with .format
    Loggers.application = logging.getLogger('{}.{}'.format(project_name, scenario_name))


    Loggers.application.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    os.makedirs('./logs/parallel/', exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs('./logs/running_info/', exist_ok=True)
    Paths.Projects.project_log_file_path = 'logs/running_info/' + project_name + '_' + scenario_name + '_running-info' + \
                                           '.log'
    my_simpler_log_format = ' %(asctime)s ::: \n %(message)s\n'
    my_log_formatter = LogFormatter(my_simpler_log_format, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", color=True)
    session_handler = RunningInfoFileHandler(Paths.Projects.project_log_file_path, mode='w')
    session_handler.setFormatter(my_log_formatter)
    session_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    Loggers.application.addHandler(session_handler)

    my_log_format = '%(color)s::: %(levelname)s %(name)s %(asctime)s ::: %(module)s:%(lineno)d in %(funcName)s :::%(end_color)s\n %(message)s\n'
    my_log_formatter = LogFormatter(fmt=my_log_format, color=True)
    Paths.Projects.project_detailed_log_file_path = 'logs/parallel/' + str(index) + '.log'
    session_detailed_handler = \
        TimedRotatingFileHandler(
            Paths.Projects.project_detailed_log_file_path,
            when='midnight',
            interval=1,
            backupCount=10)
    session_detailed_handler.setFormatter(my_log_formatter)
    session_detailed_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    Loggers.application.addHandler(session_detailed_handler)
```

I can't find any reason for the duplication, because processes are separated and log isn't initialized twice. This is also a strange form of duplication...

Comment: Can you expand a bit on how you are using multiprocessing?  Are all of the subprocesses trying to share the same log file?  Where/how is `generate_session_log_config` being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't removing logs handler after single process was terminated, thus having multiple logs.